# transponer 2 matrices de tamaño 7x7

Tags: python, array, matrices

dado dos matrices de tamaño 7x7 en uno generado de valores aleatorios, y el otro llena de ceros el usuario indicara la coordenada de la matriz de valores random y esta se traspasara a la matriz nula empezando desde la coordenada 0,0 hasta terminar con todos los valores del rango que se indico
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ejemplo en la imagen deberian de ir asi
2,4,0,4,2,0,0
8,4,5,7,3,0,0
6,5,6,0,2,0,0
5,9,2,6,9,0,0
1,3,8,6,2,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0

Comment: Buen día, el código debe estar como texto en su respectivo formato, no como imagen, ya que no todos podemos verlo y se nos hace imposible reproducir el problema. Mira [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hola Jose, bienvenido, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix1 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
          [8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
          [15,16,17,18,19,20,21],
          [22,23,24,25,26,27,28],
          [29,30,31,32,33,34,35],
          [36,37,38,39,40,41,42],
          [43,44,45,46,47,48,49]]

matrix2 = [[50,51,52,53,54,55,56],
          [57,58,59,60,61,62,63],
          [64,65,66,67,68,69,70],
          [71,72,73,74,75,76,77],
          [78,79,80,81,82,83,84],
          [85,86,87,88,89,90,91],
          [92,93,94,95,96,97,98]]

# Función para transponer una matriz
def transpose(matrix):
    return [[matrix[j][i] for j in range(len(matrix))] for i in range(len(matrix[0]))]

# Transponemos las dos matrices
matrix1_transposed = transpose(matrix1)
matrix2_transposed = transpose(matrix2)

# Imprimimos las matrices originales y transpuestas
print("Matriz 1:")
for row in matrix1:
    print(row)
print("Matriz 1 transpuesta:")
for row in matrix1_transposed:
    print(row)

print("Matriz 2:")
for row in matrix2:
    print(row)
print("Matriz 2 transpuesta:")
for row in matrix2_transposed:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Hola Osmany, bienvenido y gracias por colaborar, antes de responder, debes leer detenidamente la pregunta y los comentarios que pudiese haber, a fin de dar una respuesta acorde, este no es el caso, te sugiero que releas la pregunta y adaptes tu respuesta a la misma, de esa manera evitarás recibir votos negativos.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

matriz = [
    [ 5, 7, 1, 7, 1, 7, 1 ],
    [ 0, 2, 7, 4, 8, 1, 4 ],
    [ 7, 0, 2, 4, 0, 4, 2 ],
    [ 7, 5, 8, 4, 5, 7, 3 ],
    [ 3, 6, 6, 5, 6, 0, 2 ],
    [ 7, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 9 ],
    [ 7, 0, 1, 3, 8, 6, 2 ]]
 
def transpose( renglon, columna ):
    matriz = np.random.randint( 10, size = ( 7, 7 ))
    matriz2 = np.zeros(( 7, 7 ))
    lon = 7
    for i in range( len( matriz[ 0 ] )):
        for j in range( len( matriz )):
            matriz2[ i ][ j ] = matriz[ renglon ][ columna ]
            columna += 1
            if columna == lon:
                if renglon +1 == lon:
                    return matriz2
                else:
                    renglon += 1
                    columna = 0
    
print( transpose( 2, 2 ) )
```

Esto imprime:

```
[
    [2, 4, 0, 4, 2, 7, 5], 
    [8, 4, 5, 7, 3, 3, 6], 
    [6, 5, 6, 0, 2, 7, 1], 
    [5, 9, 2, 6, 9, 7, 0], 
    [1, 3, 8, 6, 2, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Con los `for` iteramos sobre **matriz2**, instanciando en cada iteración, la posición correspondiente.
Las variables **renglon** y **columna** nos indican desde que posición de **matriz** debemos empezar.
En cada iteración, aumentamos en "1" **columna**, luego verificamos en el primer `if`, si esta fuera de su rango, si lo está, verificamos si **renglon** más "1", quedaría fuera de su rango, en cuyo caso retornamos **matriz2**, si no, aumentamos **renglon** en "1" y ponemos **columna** a "0".

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar indexación básica que permite la librería, para esto es necesario la variable (índice o coordenada) donde se toman los valores y utilizar la longitud o *shape* del vector asignando así los valores generando de esta forma una suma, si los valores son solo ceros entonces los suma si no quieres, entonces reasignas cada elemento:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.random.randint(10,size=(7,7))
array([[5, 5, 8, 6, 8, 8, 0],
       [3, 9, 1, 7, 1, 8, 0],
       [4, 7, 3, 3, 5, 7, 9],
       [3, 4, 4, 3, 9, 0, 2],
       [6, 6, 4, 1, 5, 6, 8],
       [1, 4, 4, 0, 3, 3, 7],
       [2, 4, 1, 5, 1, 1, 7]])

>>> y = np.zeros((7,7))
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

>>> y[0:x[2:].shape[0]] += x[2:] # indice 2 e indicar shape[0] y evitar ValueError
array([[4., 7., 3., 3., 5., 7., 9.],
       [3., 4., 4., 3., 9., 0., 2.],
       [6., 6., 4., 1., 5., 6., 8.],
       [1., 4., 4., 0., 3., 3., 7.],
       [2., 4., 1., 5., 1., 1., 7.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```